# g++/clang override linker for specific functions

Tags: c++, linker, g++, clang

Is there a simple way to specify alternative functions (to the linker) to be used rather than the standard ones?

I have a wrapper around open/close/read/write system functions. I can test the functionality of the good path for these functions relatively easily.

But testing the potential errors is harder. To do this I need to get open/close/read/write to generate specific error codes for each test. Is there a way to link in alternative versions of these functions that I can then program to set the appropriate errno value before returning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linker option [`--wrap`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) is for this purpose.

Some code that calls `open`:-

**main.c**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 32

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[N] = {0};
    int fd = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
    read(fd,buf,N - 1);
    puts(buf);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

For simplicity it's a program, but it needn't be.

Using the true `open`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c
$ gcc -o prog main.o
$ echo "Hello world" > hw.txt
$ ./prog hw.txt 
Hello world
```

Your alternative `open` must be called `__wrap_open`, and
must refer to the real `open`, if it needs to, as `__real_open`:

**dbg_open.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int __real_open(const char *path, int oflag);

int __wrap_open(const char *path, int oflag)
{
    printf("In tester %s\n",__FUNCTION__);
    return __real_open(path,oflag);
}
```

There's no need to recompile `main.c` to replace `open` with `__wrap_open` in `prog`; just
reuse `main.o` in a different linkage of `prog`

```
$ gcc -Wall -c dbg_open.c
$ gcc -o prog main.o dbg_open.o -Wl,--wrap=open
$ ./prog hw.txt 
In tester __wrap_open
Hello world
```

If your `__wrap_foo` alternatives needed to knock out C++ functions
`foo` then you would need to obtain the mangling of `foo` to specify in the linkage
option `--wrap=mangled-foo`. But since you want to knock out system calls
you're spared that complication.

Comment: Excellent answer - I vaguely remembered we could do this, but it's great to see a full worked example.  Thank you!